# Tomcat 8 SSL with ArcGIS server

Tags: tomcat, ssl, arcgis, arcgis-server

I am trying get a web application running on Apache Tomcat 8 to contact an IIS service running ArcGIS Server with a self-signed certificate.

I have configured a self-signed certificate for ArcGIS server in IIS, and that's working correctly, but I'm having trouble contacting that service from the web application in Tomcat.

Comment: Is ArcGIS a web server in front of Tomcat, or is ArcGIS the web application being deployed on Tomcat?

Comment: The arcgis server is a server runing in a IIS with SSL. In the tomcat runs an application that needs comunicate with the arcgis server with ssl.

Comment: So you can already access ArcGIS via HTTPS, right? You want Tomcat to contact ArcGIS using the IIS's self-signed certificate, and your Java web application is complaining that the certificate is self-signed?

Comment: Yes, I can access to via HTTPS. The problem is that I can't configure Apache Tomcat to communicate with Arcgis with the self-signed certificate, I have errors with the certified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the self-signed certificate to the trust store of the JRE that runs Tomcat, using the JDK's `keytool` utility. The trust store is Java keystore, in this case a file called `cacerts` in `/path/to/java/lib/security`. Here is the command:

```
$ keytool -import -alias mycert -file /path/to/cert.cer -keystore /path/to/java/lib/security/cacerts
```

It will challenge you for the trust store's password. The default password for the JRE trust store is `changeit`.

Things to keep in mind:

- If you add a cert to the JRE's trust store, every application that you run with that JRE will trust that cert.
- If you upgrade the JRE or install a new JRE, its trust store will not yet contain the cert, so you will have to remember to add the cert to the new JRE's trust store.

Comment: +1 for remembering that a JRE upgrade requires you to re-import the certificate. It's easy to forget about that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, It works perfectly.
I appreciate it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this actually doesn't have anything to do with Tomcat itself, because Tomcat isn't making the HTTP connection from your web application to the ArcGIS server. Whatever component you are using to access the other server needs to know it's okay to trust that certificate.

You need to import the server's (public) certificate into a Java keystore (known as a "trust store", because you are trusting the keys in it rather than storing private keys), and tell whatever component (http-client, `HttpURLConnection`, etc.) to use that trust store when making outgoing connections.

If you only have a single web application running tomcat, you can set that trust store for the whole JVM using these system properties:

```
javax.net.ssl.trustStore (file path to the trust store)
javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword (the password to the trust store)
```

If you have to configure the web application individually, you'd better hope that the component you are using (e.g. http-client) supports setting the trust store easily, because writing the code yourself required dozens of lines of Java code that are easy to get wrong, and nothing will work.